# How to get Object ID from Application (client) ID and Directory (tenant) ID?

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory

Using the azure go sdk, is it possible to use the `Application (client) ID`, `Directory (tenant) ID`, and a valid `Client secret` to obtain the `Object ID` of the Azure Active Directory application? How?

Here is a screenshot of the Azure portal to help clarify those three fields.

[image]

I've tried to use the following [function from graphrbac](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ApplicationsClient.GetServicePrincipalsIDByAppID), but the `*result.Value` does not match with the `Object ID` from the screenshot above.

`func (client ApplicationsClient) GetServicePrincipalsIDByAppID(ctx context.Context, applicationID string) (result ServicePrincipalObjectResult, err error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your question is to get the id of the service principal(located in the `Enterprise applications` in the portal), not the azure ad application(located in the `App registrations`) which in your screenshot.

It seems there is no such function to get the `objectid` of the application via the properties that you want to use. (I am not familiar with go, if there is something wrong, please correct me.) The most similar is [`func (ApplicationsClient) Get`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ApplicationsClient.Get) which need the `objectid`, or the [`func (ApplicationsClient) List`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac#ApplicationsClient.List)  to list applications.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you may not need this now but just in case anyone is trying to do the same thing.  Below is how I currently go about doing it, but it feels super hacky though (that's why I was trying to look up if someone could achieve it via MSGraph or something a bit more elegant).

It relies on the following mechanisms:

1. Create a client using [azure-sdk-for-go's](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) [`azidentity`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/azidentity) module.  All of the client types implement azcore's [`TokenCredential`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/9286c60011675cb0eb4daa8b01f31e14e2807439/sdk/azcore/core.go#L23) interface.  With this you can get the JWT token of the client.
2. Get the token using the client and then extract the object ID (claim `oid`).  You can use [`golang-jwt`](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt) to do this.

Below is how I put it together (warning: incomplete and unsecured):

```golang
    client, _:= azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret,
        &azidentity.ClientSecretCredentialOptions{
            ClientOptions: azcore.ClientOptions{
                Cloud: cloud.AzurePublic,
            },
        })

    tokenString, _:= client.GetToken(context.Background(), policy.TokenRequestOptions{Scopes: []string{"https://management.azure.com/.default"}})

    type custom struct {
        ObjectId string `json:"oid"`
        jwt.StandardClaims
    }

    p := jwt.NewParser(jwt.WithoutClaimsValidation())
    c := &custom{}
    p.ParseUnverified(tokenString.Token, c)
    fmt.Println(c.ObjectId)
```